# combine multiple tables based on commonalities of a single column

Tags: sql

[image]

How do i make one main table that has one instance of the column 'Instructor'  and shows 'formsreturned' and 'availability_avg' next to the main 'Instructor' column?

Comment: Thanks for telling us. If you have a question please come back and ask after you have tried something.

Comment: It is dangerous to go alone. Take this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: More links for you.
<http://www.khankennels.com/blog/index.php/archives/2007/04/20/getting-joins/>
<http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html>

Answer (score 0):

Just create a standard `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.Instructor, T1.Availability_Avg, T2.FormsReturned
FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Instructor = T2.Instructor
```